# Index.php still accessible after changing it to index in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Actual Url  `www.example.com/index.php`
After rewriterule to remove .php it becomes  `www.example.com/index`.
The only problem is `www.example.com/index.php` is still accessible.
How to get rid of this ?
Rewrite rule to remove .php which i used .

```
**RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [NC,L]**
```

Comment: what do you mean with "still accessible"? The Rewrite won't block a user from successfully typing `index.php`, it will only (internally) rewrite `index` _to_ `index.php`

Comment: Then kindly tell me how i do block user to access index.php . If someone type www.example.com/index.php instead of www.example.com/index it should show error 404  url not found .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the other way around: RewriteEngine transforms the URL user provides into a local file that can be accessed (simplified version).

If user opens "http://example.com/test", rewrite engine will transform it into "test.php" by ADDING an extension.

I assume you want the user to never see ".php" in browser, so here is a solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If is has php extension, 
# let browser redirect to non-php version
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,END,R]

# If the file does not exist, add php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,END]
```

Comment: The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Facing this error after . after implementing above rule.

Comment: What exactly is the URL path you tried and what is the PHP file you expect to load?